# Error during Keras model checkpoint save: 'OSError: Unable to create file. Permission denied'

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

Around epoch number 57 of my CNN, when the model checkpoint is being saved, I get an error message:

```
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'BestF1_SMOTE_UP_Transf.hdf5'
```

The thing is, the models were saving find up to that point. Just looking at the output and it saved the model at about 15 checkpoints. Then suddenly it stopped working.

I don't know what to try, I'm stumped. Because it works fine up to that point. Something happens between epoch 56 and 57. Some googling of the problem I found people who downgraded their version of Keras, but this is a bit drastic. I've been saving models for the last couple of months without a problem. In fact my other models save fine right now. Just this particular one.. (I'm using VGGnet as a feature extractor if that matters).

The filename and checkpoint in question:

```
save_path = 'BestF1_SMOTE_UP_Transf.hdf5'

# save highest F1 out of all epochs 

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(save_path, 
                             monitor='val_f1_score',
                             verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                             mode='max')

# reduce learning rate if F1 stagnates

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_f1_score',
                              factor=0.2,patience=5,
                              min_lr=0.0001)

historynew = model.fit(train_features_vgg,ytrain,
                       batch_size=batch_size,
                       callbacks=[reduce_lr,checkpoint],
                       epochs=400,
                       validation_data=(validation_features_vgg, ytest),
                       verbose=1)
```

Full traceback here:

```
Epoch 00056: val_f1_score improved from 0.92658 to 0.92772, saving model to BestF1_SMOTE_UP_Transf.hdf5
Epoch 57/400
14243/14243 [==============================] - 5s 321us/step - loss: 0.0125 - auroc: 1.0000 - precision: 0.9965 - recall: 0.9980 - f1_score: 0.9973 - val_loss: 0.4475 - val_auroc: 0.9607 - val_precision: 0.9149 - val_recall: 0.9434 - val_f1_score: 0.9289

Epoch 00057: val_f1_score improved from 0.92772 to 0.92892, saving model to BestF1_SMOTE_UP_Transf.hdf5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-9b31dbe220b2> in <module>
      9 reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_f1_score', factor=0.2,patience=5, min_lr=0.0001)
     10 
---> 11 historynew = model.fit(train_features_vgg,ytrain, batch_size=batch_size,callbacks=[reduce_lr,checkpoint],epochs=400,validation_data=(validation_features_vgg, ytest),verbose=1)
     12 

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1037                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1038                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1039                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1040 
   1041     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    215                         for l, o in zip(out_labels, val_outs):
    216                             epoch_logs['val_' + l] = o
--> 217         callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    218         if callback_model.stop_training:
    219             break

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
     77         logs = logs or {}
     78         for callback in self.callbacks:
---> 79             callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
     80 
     81     def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    444                             self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
    445                         else:
--> 446                             self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
    447                     else:
    448                         if self.verbose > 0:

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1088             raise NotImplementedError
   1089         from ..models import save_model
-> 1090         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1091 
   1092     def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True):

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    377         opened_new_file = False
    378 
--> 379     f = h5dict(filepath, mode='w')
    380 
    381     try:

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py in __init__(self, path, mode)
    184             self._is_file = False
    185         elif isinstance(path, str):
--> 186             self.data = h5py.File(path, mode=mode)
    187             self._is_file = True
    188         elif isinstance(path, dict):

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, **kwds)
    310             with phil:
    311                 fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, **kwds)
--> 312                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
    313 
    314                 if swmr_support:

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    146         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    147     elif mode == 'w':
--> 148         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    149     elif mode == 'a':
    150         # Open in append mode (read/write).

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create()

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'BestF1_SMOTE_UP_Transf.hdf5', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)
```

Comment: have you checked you have enough disk space?

Comment: I don't think we can really answer this, permission denied is a very local problem, maybe its a shared computer and permissions changed on  the folder while the program was running?

Comment: @DrBwts just checked, I have plenty..

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro it's my own laptop, and I've been saving other models into that folder without a problem

Comment: I am facing the same problem. My checkpoints were being saved until the last time. Today, when I try to run my neural network, it fails. And I haven't been able to tell why so!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by entering admin CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the file extension ".h5" for the checkpoint file name. I have just encountered the same error message and I solved it by it.

I followed the instruction using .h5 from [the TensorFlow Keras tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load).